# Entity Framework TPH detect discriminator column

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement a custom Entity Framework migration scaffolder and sql generator that would automatically add an index for the discrimnator column. To implement this solution I'd like to detect which column is the discriminator, but so far I haven't found any official or unofficial way to do that.

I started with inspecting the contents of the [ColumnModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.model.columnmodel(v=vs.113).aspx) objects that are passed as arguments to the Generate() method of the [SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.sql.sqlservermigrationsqlgenerator(v=vs.103).aspx) and the [CSharpMigrationCodeGenerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.design.csharpmigrationcodegenerator(v=vs.113).aspx) classes, but I couldn't find anything that would point to this.

Is there any means of detecting the discriminator from inside the generators? Or maybe from metadata contained in the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through the source code on Github and going way deeper into EF than a sane person should, I think I have come up with a solution that works. Posting it here just in case somebody else might need it:

```
 var metadata = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
 var entityTypes = metadata.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.SSpace);
 // These are the entity sets
 var entitySets = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace).Single().EntitySets;
 foreach (var entitySet in entitySets)
 {
   // The mapping for the entity set
   var mapping = metadata.GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace).Single().EntitySetMappings.Single(s => s.EntitySet == entitySet);
   // If there is more than one mapping for the entity set...
   if (mapping.EntityTypeMappings.Count > 0)
   {
     // This shows that these mappings belong to a hierarchy
     var hierarchyMapping = mapping.EntityTypeMappings.SingleOrDefault(etm => etm.IsHierarchyMapping);
     if (hierarchyMapping == null)
       continue;
     // Get the conditions that contain the discriminator columns and values
     var conditions = mapping.EntityTypeMappings.SelectMany(etm => etm.Fragments.Single().Conditions).OfType<ValueConditionMapping>().ToList();
     if (conditions.Select(cc => cc.Column).Distinct().Count() > 1)
     {
       Debug.WriteLine($"{mapping.EntitySet.Name} has multiple mappings one of them being a hierachy mapping, but the fragments' conditions refer more than one distinct edm property");
       continue;
     }
     if (conditions.Select(cc => cc.Column).Distinct().Count() < 1)
     {
       Debug.WriteLine($"{mapping.EntitySet.Name} has a hierachy mapping, but none of the fragments' conditions are ValueConditionMappings");
       continue;
     }
     // This is the discriminator's name in the database
     var discriminatorColumn = conditions.First().Column.Name;
   }
 }
```

I have tested this solution with the default discriminator column and with a custom discriminator column and in both cases it was working fine. Also tested with TPT and TPC and with entity splitting and table splitting, and in all cases it showed no discriminator, so it seems to be working fine.